# Google Storage and Big files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Google Cloud Functions and bucket triggers to :

- Push Video on Cloud Storage bucket
- Extract audio from video file with ffmpeg and store it locally
- Save the audio to another bucket
- Extract the text from the audio
- Save it on another bucket
- Translate the txt file automatically

Everything is doing fine if the file is under 5MB, but after the file is never uploaded to the other bucket. I have tried to upload it on the same bucket I get the video from but no use.

I have checked the google storage nodejs code and the code is doing a stream automatically after 5Mb of upload but it never ends.

Somebody have already this issue ?

My code is doing :

```
    // Imports the Google Cloud client library
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const rimraf = require('rimraf'); // rimraf directly


// Binaries for ffmpeg
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);

/**
 * Triggered from a message on a Cloud Storage bucket.
 *
 * @param {!Object} event The Cloud Functions event.
 * @param {!Function} The callback function.
 */
exports.processFile = function(event, callback) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event));

    console.log('Processing file: ' + event.data.name);  
    const bucket = storage.bucket(event.data.bucket);
    const bucketAudio = storage.bucket('distant-bucket');
    const videoFile = bucket.file(event.data.name);
    const destination = '/tmp/' + path.basename( event.data.name );

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { return videoFile.download({
     destination: destination
   }).then((error) => {
     if (error.length > 0) {
       reject(error);
     } else {
       resolve(destination);
     }
   }) 
    })
    .then((fileinfo) => {
        const filename = destination.replace( '.mp4', '.flac' );
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            ffmpeg(fileinfo)
                .videoBitrate(19200)
                .inputOptions('-vn')
                .format('flac')
                .audioChannels(1)
                .audioBitrate(44100)
                .output(filename)
                .on('end', function() {
                    console.log('extracted audio : '+event.data.name+" to "+filename);
                    resolve(filename);
                })
                .on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                    reject(err);
                })
                .run()
        });
    })
    .then((flacOutput) => {
        console.log('save file '+flacOutput);
        const stats = fs.statSync(flacOutput)
        console.log(stats.size / 1000000.0);
        // TODO: upload FLAC file to Cloud Storage
        return bucket
          .upload( flacOutput ).catch((err) => {
          console.error('Failed to upload flac.', err);
          return Promise.reject(err);
        });
   }).then(() => {
      console.log(`Audio uploaded.`);

      // Delete the temporary file.
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.unlink(destination);
        fs.unlink(destination.replace( '.mp4', '.flac' ), (err) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve();
          }
        });
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: How long do you expect this processing to take?  Is it possible the default timeout (60s according to https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions#CloudFunction) is being exceeded?

Comment: Hello, I have set 540 seconds of timeout but it's no help.

Comment: Does access to GCS otherwise work fine in this environment? Can you run gsutil perfiag, possibly with a larger size (flag "-s 10M")? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/perfdiag

Comment: @NicolasJuen This may be an issue with multi-part uploads. I've run into the `5mb` "limit" issue you illustrated above before, but with AWS S3, not GCS. In my case the multi-part upload was split into 5mb chunks by default, and the subsequent parts (chunks) did not have the proper auth to be uploaded. Not sure if this is the same issue you're facing, but worth looking into the mechanics of multi-part uploading.